How do I decode the LoRaWAN payload in AWS IoT Core sent by RadioLib?
I am sending a 3-byte payload from LoRa ESP32 using Arduino to program the MCU.  I am successfully connecting to AWS IoT Core for LoRaWAN and publishing my uplink payloads to a topic.  However, when I decode the binary payload, I'm getting a totally different payload than what I sent.
Here is my Arduino code to uplink:
uint8_t uplinkPayload[3];
uplinkPayload[0] = 75;
uplinkPayload[1] = 83;
uplinkPayload[2] = 90;
  
RADIOLIB(node.sendReceive(uplinkPayload, sizeof(uplinkPayload), FPORT));

Here is the payload reaching my MQTT topic (remainder of MQTT payload removed for brevity):
"PayloadData": "jrrW"

Using Python to decode this, I get the following:
print(base64.b64decode("jrrW"))
b'\x8e\xba\xd6'


In other words, I'm getting 8E BA D6 which translates to 142 186 214
I've tried passing in hex to my uplink payload array and got different payload results, but they still didn't match up with what I sent.

Why do you think the 3-byte data you sent need base64 decoding at the receiving end?

That is part of the AWS LoRaWAN implementation.  They automatically base64 encode your payload.

So you are assuming node.sendReceive() will somehow did the base64 encoding for you? print out what you received before doing the base64 decoding to see what you get.

No, node.sendReceive() transmits "untampered".  AWS IoT base64 encodes the payload before routing it to the MQTT topic I'm receiving PayloadData on
